# DNS error 4011, unable to write, or update

Tags: domain-name-system, domain-controller, internal-dns, windows-server-2019, dns-zone

I encountered one intriguing issue with DNS service on a pair of our domain controllers. Frequently, about every half an hour (sometimes skips or shows only on one), I get the error ID 4011. These always come in pair.

> The DNS server was unable to add or write an update of domain name **DESKTOP-AFIOMNJ** in zone *Local.domain.name* to the Active Directory.  Check that the Active Directory is functioning properly and add or update this domain name using the DNS console. The extended error debug information (which may be empty) is "00002098: SecErr: DSID-031514A0, problem 4003 (INSUFF_ACCESS_RIGHTS), data 0". The event data contains the error.

It started spontaneously, in the middle of the day before holidays and proceeded even when most of the network was shut down due to infrastructure maintenance.
Our network is pretty big (roughly 70 workstations and additonal 150-200 terminals for machinery, some of which run windows) so going around and figuring out what is plugged in and might be causing it is unreasonable.

In DNS console, I tried to add record of DESKTOP-AFIOMNJ manually, but I got "access denied" whatever I tried, A, CNAME, AAAA, PTR, KEY, nothing works with it as a name. FYI, I tried to do it with DNS on both DCs stopped and DnsCmd as well.

I was trying to find something from DNS console with debugging, but all I got was even more confusing. IP from Remote addr is DC itself. Port is from private range, used by DNS.

```
1/23/2024 1:12:48 PM 04C0 PACKET  0000019C95C98950 UDP Rcv 10.160.200.44   6e07   Q [0001   D   NOERROR] SOA    (15)DESKTOP-AFIOMNJ(3)local(10)domain(3)name(0)
UDP question info at 0000019C95C98950
  Socket = 836
  Remote addr 10.160.200.44, port 54128
  Time Query=262231, Queued=0, Expire=0
  Buf length = 0x0fa0 (4000)
  Msg length = 0x0034 (52)
  Message:
    XID       0x6e07
    Flags     0x0100
      QR        0 (QUESTION)
      OPCODE    0 (QUERY)
      AA        0
      TC        0
      RD        1
      RA        0
      Z         0
      CD        0
      AD        0
      RCODE     0 (NOERROR)
    QCOUNT    1
    ACOUNT    0
    NSCOUNT   0
    ARCOUNT   0
    QUESTION SECTION:
    Offset = 0x000c, RR count = 0
      QTYPE   SOA (6)
      QCLASS  1
    ANSWER SECTION:
      empty
    AUTHORITY SECTION:
      empty
    ADDITIONAL SECTION:
      empty

1/23/2024 1:12:48 PM 04C0 PACKET  0000019C95C98950 UDP Snd 10.160.200.44   6e07 R Q [8385 A DR NXDOMAIN] SOA    (15)DESKTOP-AFIOMNJ(3)local(10)domain(3)name(0)
UDP response info at 0000019C95C98950
  Socket = 836
  Remote addr 10.160.200.44, port 54128
  Time Query=262231, Queued=0, Expire=0
  Buf length = 0x0200 (512)
  Msg length = 0x008f (143)
  Message:
    XID       0x6e07
    Flags     0x8583
      QR        1 (RESPONSE)
      OPCODE    0 (QUERY)
      AA        1
      TC        0
      RD        1
      RA        1
      Z         0
      CD        0
      AD        0
      RCODE     3 (NXDOMAIN)
    QCOUNT    1
    ACOUNT    0
    NSCOUNT   1
    ARCOUNT   1
    QUESTION SECTION:
    Offset = 0x000c, RR count = 0
      QTYPE   SOA (6)
      QCLASS  1
    ANSWER SECTION:
      empty
    AUTHORITY SECTION:
    Offset = 0x0034, RR count = 0
      TYPE   SOA  (6)
      CLASS  1
      TTL    3600
      DLEN   45
      DATA          SerialNo     = 2064451
        Refresh      = 900
        Retry        = 600
        Expire       = 86400
        MinimumTTL   = 3600
    ADDITIONAL SECTION:
    Offset = 0x007f, RR count = 0
      TYPE   A  (1)
      CLASS  1
      TTL    3600
      DLEN   4
      DATA   10.160.200.44
```

I would like to resolve it, even though it isn't any crippling issue, it's just my and my colleague's OCD ticking every hour.

Comment: If that is the only record that fails it may be dnstombstoned (present but not visible in the console). You may want to check adsiedit.msc. AD tombstones records before deletion. Also check the database replication and check for conflict (CNF) objects. Conflicts are common in computer account provisioning processes.

Comment: @GregAskew Thanks for the tips, but unfortunately, I wasn't able to find any tombstones related to that, replication is flawless and no conflicts. I would be happy to to try some other solutions if you can suggest something that might be causing it.